# Javascript load fresh form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a simple form which is opened within a modal when an anchor is clicked.

```
<a id="callbackLink" class="various" href="#inline">Request</a>

<div id="inline" style="display:none">
    <form id="callForm" onsubmit="callEvent(event);">
        <h3>Call Back</h3>

        <label for="Number">What number shall we call you on?</label>
        <input type="tel" id="callback-tel" placeholder=""><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

When the form is submitted, a third party library processes the form.  If the form is successful, the form is removed and a success message is displayed in the modal.

Now if you close the modal and then click the button to display the form again, it will still show the success message.  So I need a way of displaying a clean form every time the button is pressed.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

**UPDATE**
The event listener is

```
function StartClickToCall(event) {
    (event.preventDefault) ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;

    var SuccessfulRequest = function() {
        document.getElementById('ClickToCallForm').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('ClickToCallErrorMessage').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('ClickToCallSuccessMessage').style.display = 'block';
    };

    var FailedRequest = function(Request, Response) {
        document.getElementById('ClickToCallSuccessMessage').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('ClickToCallErrorMessage').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('ClickToCallErrorMessage').innerHTML = Response.ResponseMessage;
    };

    _novero.push(['NoveroCallback', 'NewCallback', {
        Destination : jQuery("#callback-tel").intlTelInput("getNumber"),
        CallbackDate : document.getElementById('CallbackDate').value
    }, SuccessfulRequest, FailedRequest]);
}
```

Comment: I expect I'd take care of that in the event handler that opens the form. What does that look like?

Comment: I have updated my question.  I am using Fancybox but I dont see anything in their functions which could help.

Answer (score 0):

$('#myModal').modal('toggle');
$('#myModal').modal('view');U can try with modal window cleaning.I think modal window seems to be problem

Answer (score 0):

you didnt post the correct part of the code

if the form is replaced by a success message, then you probably have a function that is making an ajax call and in the success callback you are removing the from HTML and put in the success message HTML

if so .. if you wan to restore the form on modal close . then you need to attach a function to close click that will remove the success message HTML and re-insert the Form HTML

EDIT:

```
$(".selector").fancybox({
    onClosed: function() {
       document.getElementById('ClickToCallForm').style.display = ‘block’;
       document.getElementById('ClickToCallErrorMessage').style.display = ‘block’;
       document.getElementById('ClickToCallSuccessMessage').style.display = ‘none’;
    };

});
```

something like this . (you deleted the fancy declaration) . the close method might have a different name

but what is happening:

on fancy modal close . switch back the styles of the form . that are overwritten in the success function

Comment: Sorry, added the correct thing now to the original question